# How to check if a word includes a character in native JavaScript (string.includes(str) not working properly)

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently trying to make a minigame where a random word is generated from a bunch of arrays. Then, the user has to guess letters to fill out the word(s). However, when I run my code, some `if` statements aren't working and I *believe that it is because I am failing to use the `includes()` wrong*.

**Question**: How can I get my code to work as needed?

Note: The arrays are at the very bottom of this post. They shouldn't be a problem for this question, but they are necessary for the code to work.

`game.js`:
Note: Sorry, I am not sure what is all necessary in this code to run. I deleted some stuff so if doesn't work, comment it to me right away.

```
const difficultyArticle = document.querySelector('#difficulty-article');
const difficultyOptions = document.querySelector('#difficulty-options');
const startGameButton = document.querySelector('#start-game');

const playArticle = document.querySelector('#play-article');
const timeDisplay = document.querySelector('#time-display');
const miniutesDisplay = document.querySelector('#minutes-display');
const secondsDisplay = document.querySelector('#seconds-display');
const categoryDisplay = document.querySelector('#category-display');
const livesDisplay = document.querySelector('#lives-display');
const startTimeButton = document.querySelector('#start-time');
const stopTimeButton = document.querySelector('#stop-time');
const resetGameButton = document.querySelector('#reset-game');
const letterGuessInput = document.querySelector('#letter-guess-input');

let maxTime = 0;
let currentTime = 0;
let currentSeconds = 0;
let currentMinutes = 0;
let lives = 0;
let difficulty;
let countDownInterval;

function playGame(maxTime, maxLives) {
    let wordInfo = determineWord();
    let randomWord = wordInfo.word;
    let category = wordInfo.category;
    alert(`${randomWord}, ${category}`);

    currentTime = maxTime;
    countDown(currentTime);

    countDownInterval = setInterval(() => {
        countDown();
        currentTime--;
    }, 1000)

    categoryDisplay.innerHTML = `Category: ${category}`;
    livesDisplay.innerHTML = `Lives Left: ${lives}`;
}

function determineWord() {
    let categories = Object.keys(PlayingArrays);
    let category = categories.at(Math.floor(Math.random() * categories.length));
    let words = PlayingArrays[category];
    let randomWord = words.at(Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length));

    return {
        word: randomWord,
        category: category
    }
}

function countDown() {
    currentSeconds = currentTime % 60;
    currentMinutes = Math.floor(currentTime / 60);
    currentSeconds = currentSeconds < 10 ? `0${currentSeconds}` : `${currentSeconds}`;
    currentMinutes = currentMinutes < 10 ? `0${currentMinutes}` : `${currentMinutes}`;

    if (currentMinutes == 0 && currentSeconds <= 30) {
        secondsDisplay.style.color = "red";
        miniutesDisplay.style.color = "red";
    }

    secondsDisplay.innerHTML = currentSeconds;
    miniutesDisplay.innerHTML = currentMinutes;
}

function validateInput() {
    letterGuessInput.value = letterGuessInput.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, ''); 
}

playArticle.classList.add("hidden");
resultArticle.classList.add("hidden");

startGameButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let difficulty = difficultyOptions.value;

    if (difficulty == "Easy") {
        maxTime = 300;
        lives = 8;
    }

    if (difficulty == "Medium") {
        maxTime = 225;
        lives = 5;
    }

    if (difficulty == "Hard") {
        maxTime = 150;
        lives = 3;
    }

    if (difficulty == "Impossible") {
        maxTime = 75;
        lives = 1;
    }
    
    difficultyArticle.classList.add("hidden");
    playArticle.classList.remove("hidden");
    playGame(maxTime, lives);
})

startTimeButton.disabled = true;

stopTimeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    startTimeButton.disabled = false;
    stopTimeButton.disabled = true;
    letterGuessInput.disabled = true;
    clearInterval(countDownInterval);
})

startTimeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    startTimeButton.disabled = true;
    stopTimeButton.disabled = false;
    letterGuessInput.disabled = false;

    countDownInterval = setInterval(() => {
        countDown();
        currentTime--;
    }, 1000)
})

resetGameButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let confirmation = confirm("Are you sure you want to restart the game?");

    if (confirmation) {
        location.reload();
    }
})

letterGuessInput.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key == 'Enter' && letterGuessInput.value != "") {
        let letterGuess = letterGuessInput.value;
        
        if (randomWord.includes(letterGuess)) {
            alert(letterGuess);
            letterGuessInput.reset();
        } else {
            livesDisplay.innerHTML = `${lives} - 1`;
            lives--;

            setTimeout(() => {
                livesDisplay.innerHTML = lives;
            }, 2500)

            letterGuessInput.reset();
        }
    }
})
```

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Christian Davis">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>Guess That Word</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <article id="difficulty-article">

            <div id="title-display">
                <h1>Guess That</h1>
                &nbsp;
                <h2>WORD!</h2>
            </div>

            <div id="difficulty-display">
                <p>Difficulty only determines the the number of lives and the time you get.</p>

                <select required id="difficulty-options">
                    <option value="">---Select Your Difficulty---</option>
                    <option value="Easy">Easy</option>
                    <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
                    <option value="Hard">Hard</option>
                    <option value="Impossible">Impossible</option>
                </select> <br>

                <button id="start-game">Start Game</button>
            </div>

            <img src="./Images/Question Mark Man.jpeg">
        </article>

        <article id="play-article">
            <div id="top-screen-display">
                <div id="time-display">
                    Time left:
                    <span id="minutes-display" class="time">00</span>:<span id="seconds-display" class="time">00</span>
                </div>

                <span id="category-display"></span> <br>
                <span id="lives-display"></span>
        
                <div id="button-container">
                    <button id="start-time" class="buttons">Resume Time</button>
                    <button id="stop-time" class="buttons">Stop Time</button>
                    <button id="reset-game" class="buttons">Reset Game</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="letter-guesser">
                <input id="letter-guess-input" type="text" maxlength="1" title="Letters Only" placeholder="Your Letter Guess" oninput="validateInput()" required>
            </div>
        </article>

        <script src="game.js"></script>
        <script src="Arrays.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

`styles.css`:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

#difficulty-article.hidden, #play-article.hidden, #result-article.hidden {
    display: none;
}

#title-display {
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: baseline;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 18pt;
}

#title-display h1 {
    font-weight: 300;
}

#title-display h2 {
    font-weight: 800;
    color: red;
}

#difficulty-display h2, #difficulty-display h1 {
    position: relative;
    left: 42.5vw;
}

#difficulty-display p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 8pt;
}

#difficulty-display select, #difficulty-display button {
    position: relative;
    left: 42.5vw;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12pt;
    width: 15vw;
    height: 5vh;
}

#play-article {
    font-size: 18pt;
}

#top-screen-display {
    text-align: center;
}

.buttons {
    width: 10vw;
    height: 5vh;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

#letter-guesser {
    text-align: center;
    height: 10vh;
    position: relative;
    top: 60vh;
}

#letter-guess-input {
    width: 15vw;
    height: 10vh;
    font-size: 18pt;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

`Arrays.js`

```
const Animals = [
    "Aardvark",
    "Albatross",
    "Alligator",
    "Ant",
    "Armadillo",
    "Axolotl",
    "Aye-Aye",
    "Badger",
    "Banded Palm Civet",
    "Bandicoot",
    "Barnacle",
    "Barracuda",
    "Basilisk Lizard",
    "Basking Shark",
    "Bear",
    "Beaver",
    "Bedbug",
    "Bee",
    "Beetle",
    "Binturong",
    "Bird",
    "Birds Of Paradise",
    "Bison",
    "Blobfish",
    "Booby",
    "Bongo",
    "Bonito Fish",
    "Bonobo",
    "Booby",
    "Bovid",
    "Buffalo",
    "Bug",
    "Butterfly",
    "Buzzard",
    "Carp",
    "Cat",
    "Cheetah",
    "Chameleon",
    "Cockroach",
    "Cod",
    "Coelacanth",
    "Cheetah",
    "Chameleon",
    "Dolphin",
    "Duck",
    "Elephant",
    "Eagle",
    "Fox",
    "Frog",
    "Giraffe",
    "Gorilla",
    "Hawk",
    "Hippopotamus",
    "Iguana",
    "Ibis",
    "Jaguar",
    "Jellyfish",
    "Kangaroo",
    "Koala",
    "Lemur",
    "Lion",
    "Meerkat",
    "Monkey",
    "Narwhal",
    "Newt",
    "Orangutan",
    "Ostrich",
    "Penguin",
    "Peacock",
    "Quetzal",
    "Quokka",
    "Raccoon",
    "Rhinoceros",
    "Shark",
    "Sloth",
    "Tiger",
    "Toucan",
    "Uakari",
    "Umbrellabird",
    "Viper",
    "Vulture",
    "Wallaby",
    "Wombat",
    "X-ray Tetra",
    "Xenops",
    "Yabby",
    "Yak",
    "Zebra",
    "Zorse",
    "Albatross",
    "Aye-Aye",
    "Badger",
    "Banded Palm Civet",
    "Bandicoot",
    "Barnacle",
    "Barracuda",
    "Basilisk Lizard",
    "Basking Shark",
    "Bison",
    "Blobfish",
    "Booby",
    "Bongo",
    "Bonito Fish",
    "Bonobo",
    "Bovid",
    "Buffalo",
    "Bug",
    "Butterfly",
    "Buzzard",
    "Carp",
    "Cat",
    "Cockroach",
    "Cod",
    "Coelacanth",
    "Cuttlefish",
    "Dung Beetle",
    "Earwig",
    "Echidna",
    "Falcon",
    "Fiddler Crab",
    "Firefly",
    "Flatworm",
    "Flying Squirrel",
    "Gazelle",
    "Gecko",
    "Gibbon",
    "Glass Lizard",
    "Glow Worm",
    "Gnu",
    "Goblin Shark",
    "Goldfish",
    "Goose",
    "Gopher",
    "Gudgeon",
    "Guinea Pig",
    "Guppy",
    "Hamster",
    "Harpy Eagle",
    "Hercules Beetle",
    "Hermit Crab",
    "Herring",
    "Hornet",
    "Hummingbird",
    "Hyena",
    "Ibex",
    "Impala",
    "Indigo Bunting",
    "Insect",
    "Jackal",
    "Jerboa",
    "Junglefowl",
    "Kinkajou",
    "Kiwi",
    "Kookaburra",
    "Kowari",
    "Lamprey",
    "Leaf-Tailed Gecko",
    "Leech",
    "Lemming",
    "Limpet",
    "Lobster",
    "Locust",
    "Mantis Shrimp",
    "Mantis",
    "Marmoset",
    "Marsupial",
    "Mastodon",
    "Mayfly",
    "Midge",
    "Millipede",
    "Mole",
    "Mollusk",
    "Mongoose",
    "Monitor Lizard",
    "Moth",
    "Mouse",
    "Mule",
    "Nightingale",
    "Nudibranch",
    "Numbat",
    "Nurse Shark",
    "Okapi",
    "Olm",
    "Opossum",
    "Owl",
    "Panda",
    "Parrot",
    "Peafowl",
    "Pelican",
    "Penguin",
    "Pheasant",
    "Pig",
    "Pika",
    "Piranha",
    "Planarian",
    "Platypus",
    "Poodle",
    "Porcupine",
    "Quail",
    "Quokka",
    "Quoll",
    "Rabbit",
    "Rat",
    "Reindeer",
    "Reticulated Python",
    "Rhinoceros",
    "Sable",
    "Salamander",
    "Sardine",
    "Scorpion",
    "Sea Dragon",
    "Sea Slug",
    "Sea Squirt",
    "Sea Urchin",
    "Seahorse",
    "Seal",
    "Shrimp",
    "Skunk",
    "Sloth",
    "Slug",
    "Snail",
    "Snake",
    "Snipe",
    "Snow Leopard",
    "Sparrow",
    "Spider",
    "Sponge",
    "Squid",
    "Squirrel",
    "Star-Nosed Mole",
    "Starfish",
    "Stonefish",
    "Sturgeon",
    "Sun Bear",
    "Swordfish",
    "Tapeworm",
    "Tarantula",
    "Tarsier",
    "Termite",
    "Thorny Devil",
    "Tiger Beetle",
    "Tiger Shark",
    "Tiger Snake",
    "Tiglon",
    "Tortoise",
    "Toucan",
    "Tree Frog",
    "Tsetse Fly",
    "Uakari",
    "Uguisu",
    "Umbrellabird",
    "Unicorn",
    "Urial",
    "Vampire Bat",
    "Vampire Squid",
    "Vicuna",
    "Vulture",
    "Wallaby",
    "Walrus",
    "Warthog",
    "Wasp",
    "Water Buffalo",
    "Weasel",
    "Weevil",
    "Whale",
    "Whippet",
    "Whitefish",
    "Wild Boar",
    "Wildebeest",
    "Wolf",
    "Wolverine",
    "Wombat",
    "Woodpecker",
    "Wrasse",
    "Wrench",
    "Wryneck",
    "X-Ray Tetra",
    "X-Ray Fish",
    "Xantus's Hummingbird",
    "Xeme",
    "Xenarthra",
    "Xenomorph",
    "Xenophyophore",
    "Xenops",
    "Xenopus",
    "Xerus",
    "Xiaosaurus",
    "Xoloitzcuintli",
    "X-Ray Crab",
    "X-Ray Shrimp",
    "Yaffle",
    "Yak",
    "Yapok",
    "Yardang",
    "Yellow-Eyed Penguin",
    "Yellowjacket",
    "Yelling Cat",
    "Yerevan",
    "Yeti Crab",
    "Yew",
    "Ylva",
    "Yo-Yo",
    "Yodeler",
    "Yoshi",
    "Yowie",
    "Yoyo",
    "Yurt",
    "Zander",
    "Zebra",
    "Zebu",
    "Zedonk",
    "Zebra Shark",
    "Zebra Turkeyfish",
    "Zorse"
]

const People = [
    { firstName: "Christian", lastName: "Davis" },
    { firstName: "Ada", lastName: "Lovelace" },
    { firstName: "Abraham", lastName: "Lincoln" },
    { firstName: "Albert", lastName: "Einstein" },
    { firstName: "Alice", lastName: "Johnson" },
    { firstName: "Barack", lastName: "Obama" },
    { firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Smith" },
    { firstName: "Cleopatra", lastName: "Jones" },
    { firstName: "Charles", lastName: "Darwin" },
    { firstName: "Charlie", lastName: "Davis" },
    { firstName: "Coco", lastName: "Chanel" },
    { firstName: "David", lastName: "Bowie" },
    { firstName: "Emily", lastName: "Brown" },
    { firstName: "Emmeline", lastName: "Pankhurst" },
    { firstName: "Frank", lastName: "Johnson" },
    { firstName: "Frida", lastName: "Kahlo" },
    { firstName: "Galileo", lastName: "Galilei" },
    { firstName: "Grace", lastName: "Taylor" },
    { firstName: "Grace", lastName: "Hopper" },
    { firstName: "Henry", lastName: "Clark" },
    { firstName: "Helen", lastName: "Keller" },
    { firstName: "Ivy", lastName: "Robinson" },
    { firstName: "Isaac", lastName: "Newton" },
    { firstName: "Jack", lastName: "Anderson" },
    { firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Austen" },
    { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" },
    { firstName: "John", lastName: "Kennedy" },
    { firstName: "Katherine", lastName: "Miller" },
    { firstName: "Kylie", lastName: "Johnson" },
    { firstName: "Leonardo", lastName: "da Vinci" },
    { firstName: "Louis", lastName: "Turner" },
    { firstName: "Mia", lastName: "Hill" },
    { firstName: "Marie", lastName: "Curie" },
    { firstName: "Martin", lastName: "King Jr." },
    { firstName: "Nelson", lastName: "Mandela" },
    { firstName: "Noah", lastName: "Parker" },
    { firstName: "Olivia", lastName: "Rossi" },
    { firstName: "Pablo", lastName: "Picasso" },
    { firstName: "Paul", lastName: "White" },
    { firstName: "Quinn", lastName: "Miller" },
    { firstName: "Queen", lastName: "Elizabeth II" },
    { firstName: "Robert", lastName: "Davis" },
    { firstName: "Rosa", lastName: "Parks" },
    { firstName: "Sophia", lastName: "Walker" },
    { firstName: "Steve", lastName: "Jobs" },
    { firstName: "Thomas", lastName: "Edison" },
    { firstName: "Tom", lastName: "Thompson" },
    { firstName: "Ursula", lastName: "Smith" },
    { firstName: "Victor", lastName: "Garcia" },
    { firstName: "Vincent", lastName: "van Gogh" },
    { firstName: "Wendy", lastName: "Jones" },
    { firstName: "William", lastName: "Shakespeare" },
    { firstName: "Winston", lastName: "Churchill" },
    { firstName: "Xander", lastName: "Johnson" },
    { firstName: "Yvonne", lastName: "Miller" },
    { firstName: "Zachary", lastName: "Wilson" },
    { firstName: "Zhang", lastName: "Heng" }
]

const Buildings = [
    "Angkor Wat",
    "Big Ben",
    "Brandenburg Gate",
    "Burj Khalifa",
    "Christ the Redeemer",
    "Colosseum",
    "Eiffel Tower",
    "Forbidden City",
    "Great Wall of China",
    "Hagia Sophia",
    "Louvre Museum",
    "Machu Picchu",
    "Neuschwanstein Castle",
    "Petra",
    "Pyramids of Giza",
    "Sagrada Familia",
    "Sydney Opera House",
    "Taj Mahal",
    "The White House",
    "Tokyo Tower",
    "Alhambra",
    "Amsterdam Centraal",
    "Atomium",
    "Basilica of the Sagrada Familia",
    "Blue Mosque",
    "Buckingham Palace",
    "Casa Milà",
    "Casa Batlló",
    "Château de Versailles",
    "Cologne Cathedral",
    "Dresden Frauenkirche",
    "Dome of the Rock",
    "Edinburgh Castle",
    "Empire State Building",
    "Fallingwater",
    "Florence Cathedral",
    "Gherkin",
    "Golden Gate Bridge",
    "Great Mosque of Djenne",
    "Himeji Castle",
    "Hofburg",
    "Hollywood Sign",
    "Jin Mao Tower",
    "Leaning Tower of Pisa",
    "Mont Saint-Michel",
    "Moscow Kremlin",
    "Palace of Westminster",
    "Pantheon",
    "Potala Palace",
    "Reichstag Building",
    "Rockefeller Center",
    "St. Basil's Cathedral",
    "St. Peter's Basilica",
    "Statue of Liberty",
    "Stonehenge",
    "Taipei 101",
    "The Shard",
    "Tower Bridge",
    "Uffizi Gallery",
    "Willis Tower",
    "Windsor Castle",
    "Yellow Crane Tower"
]

const Climates = [
    "Alpine",
    "Arid",
    "Boreal Forest",
    "Chaparral",
    "Coastal",
    "Cold Alpine",
    "Cold Arid",
    "Cold Continental",
    "Cold Desert",
    "Cold Highland",
    "Cold Monsoon",
    "Cold Oceanic",
    "Cold Prairie",
    "Cold Rainforest",
    "Cold Savannah",
    "Cold Steppe",
    "Cold Swamp",
    "Cold Temperate",
    "Cold Tundra",
    "Cold Wetland",
    "Cold Oceanic",
    "Cold Ice Cap",
    "Desert",
    "Dry Continental",
    "Dry Desert",
    "Dry Highland",
    "Dry Ice Cap",
    "Dry Oceanic",
    "Dry Prairie",
    "Dry Rainforest",
    "Dry Savannah",
    "Dry Steppe",
    "Dry Swamp",
    "Dry Tundra",
    "Dry Wetland",
    "Equatorial",
    "Equatorial Guinea Climate",
    "Equatorial Monsoon",
    "Equatorial Rainforest",
    "Hot Alpine",
    "Hot Arid",
    "Hot Continental",
    "Hot Desert",
    "Hot Highland",
    "Hot Ice Cap",
    "Hot Oceanic",
    "Hot Prairie",
    "Hot Rainforest",
    "Hot Savannah",
    "Hot Steppe",
    "Hot Swamp",
    "Hot Tundra",
    "Hot Wetland",
    "Hot Oceanic",
    "Hot Steppe",
    "Hot Savannah",
    "Hot Prairie",
    "Hot Swamp",
    "Hot Alpine",
    "Hot Rainforest",
    "Hot Monsoon",
    "Hot Desert",
    "Hot Highland",
    "Hot Tundra",
    "Hot Ice Cap",
    "Humid Continental",
    "Humid Subtropical",
    "Ice Cap",
    "Mangrove",
    "Mediterranean",
    "Mediterranean Forest",
    "Monsoon",
    "Mountain",
    "Polar",
    "Polar Alpine",
    "Polar Desert",
    "Polar Ice Cap",
    "Polar Maritime",
    "Polar Tundra",
    "Polar Wetland",
    "Polar Oceanic",
    "Prairie",
    "Savanna",
    "Semi-Arid",
    "Steppe",
    "Subarctic",
    "Subtropical Desert",
    "Subtropical Highland",
    "Subtropical Oceanic",
    "Subtropical Steppe",
    "Subtropical Wetland",
    "Swamp",
    "Taiga",
    "Temperate Oceanic",
    "Temperate Rainforest",
    "Thundra",
    "Tropical Arid",
    "Tropical Continental",
    "Tropical Desert",
    "Tropical Highland",
    "Tropical Monsoon",
    "Tropical Oceanic",
    "Tropical Rainforest",
    "Tropical Savannah",
    "Tropical Wetland",
    "Tundra",
    "Warm Arid",
    "Warm Oceanic",
    "Warm Steppe",
    "Wetland",
    "Xanthus's Hummingbird",
    "Xeme",
    "Xenomorph",
    "Xenophyophore",
    "Xenops",
    "Xenopus",
    "Xerus",
    "Xiaosaurus",
    "Xoloitzcuintli",
    "X-Ray Crab",
    "X-Ray Fish",
    "X-Ray Shrimp",
    "Yellow-Eyed Penguin",
    "Yellowjacket",
    "Yelling Cat",
    "Yerevan",
    "Yeti Crab",
    "Yew",
    "Ylva",
    "Yo-Yo",
    "Yodeler",
    "Yoshi",
    "Yowie",
    "Yoyo",
    "Yurt",
    "Zander",
    "Zebra",
    "Zebra Shark",
    "Zebra Turkeyfish",
    "Zedonk"
]

const Countries = [
    "Afghanistan",
    "Albania",
    "Algeria",
    "American Samoa",
    "Andorra",
    "Angola",
    "Anguilla",
    "Antarctica",
    "Antigua and Barbuda",
    "Argentina",
    "Armenia",
    "Aruba",
    "Australia",
    "Austria",
    "Azerbaijan",
    "Bahamas",
    "Bahrain",
    "Bangladesh",
    "Barbados",
    "Belarus",
    "Belgium",
    "Belize",
    "Benin",
    "Bermuda",
    "Bhutan",
    "Bolivia",
    "Bonaire", 
    "Sint Eustatius",
    "Saba",
    "Bosnia and Herzegovina",
    "Botswana",
    "Bouvet Island",
    "Brazil",
    "British Indian Ocean Territory",
    "Brunei Darussalam",
    "Bulgaria",
    "Burkina Faso",
    "Burundi",
    "Cabo Verde",
    "Cambodia",
    "Cameroon",
    "Canada",
    "Cayman Islands",
    "Central African Republic",
    "Chad",
    "Chile",
    "China",
    "Christmas Island",
    "Cocos Islands",
    "Colombia",
    "Comoros",
    "Democratic Republic of the Congo",
    "The Congo",
    "Cook Islands",
    "Costa Rica",
    "Croatia",
    "Cuba",
    "Curaçao",
    "Cyprus",
    "Czechia",
    "Côte d'Ivoire",
    "Denmark",
    "Djibouti",
    "Dominica",
    "Dominican Republic",
    "Ecuador",
    "Egypt",
    "El Salvador",
    "Equatorial Guinea",
    "Eritrea",
    "Estonia",
    "Eswatini",
    "Ethiopia",
    "Falkland Islands",
    "Faroe Islands",
    "Fiji",
    "Finland",
    "France",
    "French Guiana",
    "French Polynesia",
    "Gabon",
    "Gambia",
    "Georgia",
    "Germany",
    "Ghana",
    "Gibraltar",
    "Greece",
    "Greenland",
    "Grenada",
    "Guadeloupe",
    "Guam",
    "Guatemala",
    "Guernsey",
    "Guinea",
    "Guinea-Bissau",
    "Guyana",
    "Haiti",
    "Heard Island",
    "Holy See",
    "Honduras",
    "Hong Kong",
    "Hungary",
    "Iceland",
    "India",
    "Indonesia",
    "Islamic Republic of Iran",
    "Iraq",
    "Ireland",
    "Isle of Man",
    "Israel",
    "Italy",
    "Jamaica",
    "Japan",
    "Jersey",
    "Jordan",
    "Kazakhstan",
    "Kenya",
    "Kiribati",
    "Democratic People's Republic of Korea",
    "Republic of Korea",
    "Kuwait",
    "Kyrgyzstan",
    "Lao People's Democratic Republic",
    "Latvia",
    "Lebanon",
    "Lesotho",
    "Liberia",
    "Libya",
    "Liechtenstein",
    "Lithuania",
    "Luxembourg",
    "Macao",
    "Madagascar",
    "Malawi",
    "Malaysia",
    "Maldives",
    "Mali",
    "Malta",
    "Marshall Islands",
    "Martinique",
    "Mauritania",
    "Mauritius",
    "Mayotte",
    "Mexico",
    "Micronesia",
    "Moldova",
    "Monaco",
    "Mongolia",
    "Montenegro",
    "Montserrat",
    "Morocco",
    "Mozambique",
    "Myanmar",
    "Namibia",
    "Nauru",
    "Nepal",
    "Netherlands",
    "New Caledonia",
    "New Zealand",
    "Nicaragua",
    "Niger",
    "Nigeria",
    "Niue",
    "Norfolk Island",
    "Mariana Islands",
    "Norway",
    "Oman",
    "Pakistan",
    "Palau",
    "Palestine",
    "Panama",
    "Papua New Guinea",
    "Paraguay",
    "Peru",
    "Philippines",
    "Pitcairn",
    "Poland",
    "Portugal",
    "Puerto Rico",
    "Qatar",
    "Macedonia",
    "Romania",
    "Russia",
    "Rwanda",
    "Réunion",
    "Saint Barthélemy",
    "Saint Helena",
    "Saint Kitts",
    "Saint Lucia",
    "Saint Martin",
    "Saint Pierre",
    "Saint Vincent",
    "Samoa",
    "San Marino",
    "Sao Tome and Principe",
    "Saudi Arabia",
    "Senegal",
    "Serbia",
    "Seychelles",
    "Sierra Leone",
    "Singapore",
    "Sint Maarten",
    "Slovakia",
    "Slovenia",
    "Solomon Islands",
    "Somalia",
    "South Africa",
    "South Georgia",
    "South Sudan",
    "Spain",
    "Sri Lanka",
    "Sudan",
    "Suriname",
    "Svalbard and Jan Mayen",
    "Sweden",
    "Switzerland",
    "Syrian Arab Republic",
    "Taiwan",
    "Tajikistan",
    "Tanzania",
    "Thailand",
    "Timor-Leste",
    "Togo",
    "Tokelau",
    "Tonga",
    "Trinidad and Tobago",
    "Tunisia",
    "Turkey",
    "Turkmenistan",
    "Turks and Caicos",
    "Tuvalu",
    "Uganda",
    "Ukraine",
    "United Arab Emirates",
    "United Kingdom",
    "United States",
    "Uruguay",
    "Uzbekistan",
    "Vanuatu",
    "Venezuela",
    "Vietnam",
    "Virgin Islands",
    "Virgin Islands",
    "Wallis and Futuna",
    "Western Sahara",
    "Yemen",
    "Zambia",
    "Zimbabwe",
    "Åland Islands"
]

const States = [
    "Alabama",
    "Alaska",
    "Arizona",
    "Arkansas",
    "California",
    "Colorado",
    "Connecticut",
    "Delaware",
    "Florida",
    "Georgia",
    "Hawaii",
    "Idaho",
    "Illinois",
    "Indiana",
    "Iowa",
    "Kansas",
    "Kentucky",
    "Louisiana",
    "Maine",
    "Maryland",
    "Massachusetts",
    "Michigan",
    "Minnesota",
    "Mississippi",
    "Missouri",
    "Montana",
    "Nebraska",
    "Nevada",
    "New Hampshire",
    "New Jersey",
    "New Mexico",
    "New York",
    "North Carolina",
    "North Dakota",
    "Ohio",
    "Oklahoma",
    "Oregon",
    "Pennsylvania",
    "Rhode Island",
    "South Carolina",
    "South Dakota",
    "Tennessee",
    "Texas",
    "Utah",
    "Vermont",
    "Virginia",
    "Washington",
    "West Virginia",
    "Wisconsin",
    "Wyoming"
]

const Capitals = [
    "Montgomery",
    "Juneau",
    "Phoenix",
    "Little Rock",
    "Sacramento",
    "Denver",
    "Hartford",
    "Dover",
    "Tallahassee",
    "Atlanta",
    "Honolulu",
    "Boise",
    "Springfield",
    "Indianapolis",
    "Des Moines",
    "Topeka",
    "Frankfort",
    "Baton Rouge",
    "Augusta",
    "Annapolis",
    "Boston",
    "Lansing",
    "St. Paul",
    "Jackson",
    "Jefferson City",
    "Helena",
    "Lincoln",
    "Carson City",
    "Concord",
    "Trenton",
    "Santa Fe",
    "Albany",
    "Raleigh",
    "Bismarck",
    "Columbus",
    "Oklahoma City",
    "Salem",
    "Harrisburg",
    "Providence",
    "Columbia",
    "Pierre",
    "Nashville",
    "Austin",
    "Salt Lake City",
    "Montpelier",
    "Richmond",
    "Olympia",
    "Charleston",
    "Madison",
    "Cheyenne",
    "Tokyo",       // Japan
    "Paris",       // France
    "Berlin",      // Germany
    "Cairo",       // Egypt
    "Moscow",      // Russia
    "Seoul",       // South Korea
    "Oslo",        // Norway
    "Wellington",  // New Zealand
    "Beijing",     // China
    "Rome",        // Italy
    "Dublin",      // Ireland
    "Canberra",    // Australia
    "Nairobi",     // Kenya
    "Bangkok",     // Thailand
    "Stockholm",   // Sweden
    "Amsterdam",   // Netherlands
    "Brasília",    // Brazil
    "Lisbon",      // Portugal
    "Ottawa"       // Canada
]

const Foods = [
    "Almond",
    "Apple",
    "Apple Pie",
    "Asparagus",
    "Banana",
    "Barley",
    "Beef",
    "Broccoli",
    "Brownie",
    "Butter",
    "Candy",
    "Carrot",
    "Cheese",
    "Cherry",
    "Chicken",
    "Couscous",
    "Daikon",
    "Date",
    "Doughnut",
    "Duck",
    "Durian",
    "Eclair",
    "Egg",
    "Eggplant",
    "Elderberry",
    "Einkorn",
    "Evaporated Milk",
    "Fennel",
    "Feta",
    "Fig",
    "Fish",
    "Fudge",
    "Gelato",
    "Garlic",
    "Grapes",
    "Grits",
    "Grouper",
    "Habanero",
    "Halibut",
    "Havarti",
    "Hempseed",
    "Honeydew",
    "Hot Fudge Sundae",
    "Ice Cream",
    "Ice Cream Sandwich",
    "Iceberg Lettuce",
    "Israeli Couscous",
    "Jalapeño Jack",
    "Jelly Beans",
    "Jellyfish",
    "Kiwi",
    "Kale",
    "Kamut",
    "Kettle Corn",
    "Lamb",
    "Lemon",
    "Lemon Bars",
    "Lettuce",
    "Macarons",
    "Mango",
    "Milk",
    "Mousse",
    "Mushroom",
    "Mussels",
    "Napa Cabbage",
    "Natto",
    "Nondairy Yogurt",
    "Nougat",
    "Oatmeal Raisin Cookies",
    "Olive Oil",
    "Orange",
    "Ostrich",
    "Papaya",
    "Parmesan",
    "Peach",
    "Pear",
    "Pecan",
    "Pepper",
    "Pesto",
    "Pineapple",
    "Pork",
    "Potato",
    "Pudding",
    "Pumpkin",
    "Quark",
    "Quiche",
    "Quinoa",
    "Raspberry",
    "Rice",
    "Sausage",
    "Shrimp",
    "Sorghum",
    "Soy Milk",
    "Spinach",
    "Strawberry",
    "Sushi",
    "Taco",
    "Tapioca",
    "Tea",
    "Teff",
    "Toffee",
    "Udon",
    "Vanilla",
    "Walnut",
    "Watermelon",
    "Wonton",
    "Yogurt"
]

const PlayingArrays = {
    Animals, 
    People,
    Buildings,
    Climates,
    Countries,
    States,
    Capitals,
    Foods
}
```

Comment: You should be getting an error in the console saying that `randomWord` is undefined. It's a local variable in `playGame`, not a global variable that you can access in the event listener.